# NVidia Thrust device_vector of strings

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I started using the NVidia Thrust library which comes as part of the CUDA 4.0 toolkit and wanted to verify something before digging deeper.  I can perform the following and have no issues during build:

```
thrust::host_vector <int> iVec;
thrust::device_vector <int> iVec2;
thrust::host_vector <std::string> sVec;
```

When I try the following I get a compilation error:

```
    thrust::device_vector <std::string> sVec2;
```

What I would like to know is can I assume any data type I can use in an STL vector should be useable in a thrust vector irrespective of whether it's device or host?  Or are there limitations here and I shouldn't expect this to work?

The error I get is the following:

c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\device\cuda\for_each.inl(93): error C2027: use of undefined type 'thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              x=false
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\device\dispatch\for_each.h(56) : see reference to function template instantiation 'RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::device::cuda::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator,Size,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              RandomAccessIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              Size=__w64 int,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\device\for_each.inl(43) : see reference to function template instantiation 'RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::device::dispatch::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator,Size,UnaryFunction,thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              RandomAccessIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              OutputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              Size=__w64 int,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\device\for_each.inl(54) : see reference to function template instantiation 'OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::for_each_n(OutputIterator,Size,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              OutputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              InputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor,
1>              Size=__w64 int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\dispatch\for_each.h(72) : see reference to function template instantiation 'InputIterator thrust::detail::device::for_each(InputIterator,InputIterator,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              InputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\for_each.inl(51) : see reference to function template instantiation 'InputIterator thrust::detail::dispatch::for_each(InputIterator,InputIterator,UnaryFunction,thrust::device_space_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              InputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\for_each.inl(67) : see reference to function template instantiation 'InputIterator thrust::detail::for_each(InputIterator,InputIterator,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              InputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\dispatch\destroy.h(59) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::for_each>(InputIterator,InputIterator,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              ForwardIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              T=value_type,
1>              InputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::device_destroy_functor
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\destroy.h(42) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::detail::dispatch::destroy(ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator,thrust::detail::false_type)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              ForwardIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\vector_base.inl(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::detail::destroy>(ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Pointer=thrust::device_ptr,
1>              ForwardIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\detail\vector_base.inl(440) : while compiling class template member function 'thrust::detail::vector_base::~vector_base(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string,
1>              Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v4.0\include\thrust\device_vector.h(55) : see reference to class template instantiation 'thrust::detail::vector_base' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string,
1>              Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\fsquared\mydata\idata\main.cpp(119) : see reference to class template instantiation 'thrust::device_vector' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I am using MSCV 2010 here.

Comment: I have no experience with either CUDA or thrust (therefore this is not an answer), but I think the datatype has to be supported on the device, which I doubt for a C++ class to be supported in CUDA. Also keep in mind that std::string is not a simple standard data type, but a C++ class, also not a simple one (much template stuff). It could work with pointers to strings or with plain old char arrays, but all that I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA does not support standard C++ container types in device code, it is basically limited to C++ POD types only. You can define your own classes for use on the GPU, but the constructor and member functions must be defined as CUDA `__device__` functions, and there are still a number of limitations on what language features are support in device code.